# Link to external file in android

Tags: android-layout

Can any one tell me how we can give an link to external file so that when the button is clicked that displays the content of that file in the device...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `layouts`, `styles`, `animations` etc. you can use only links to other resources. So, put the file content in `drawable` or `string` in one of the XML resources or if you really need to use a file out of resources, do it in code.